# Jobs run by GNU parallel don't seem to be parallel

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I wanted to use GNU parallel tool to make rsync file transfer to several hosts faster, but it seems that the parallel tool doesn't make it parallel much.

I expected `time parallel "sleep 5; echo {}" ::: 1 2 3` to take not much longer than 5 seconds, but in real, it is:

`real 0m16.306s
user    0m0.275s
sys 0m0.108s`

which seems to be the same as `for i in 1 2 3; sleep 5; done` i.e. not parallelized at all. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `parallel -j 3`
                    – Mark Setchell